# Symfony type validation not working - always returns 'This value should not be blank'

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm having some trouble with Symfony form validation in 2.1.7.

When I bind my data to a form, all I get for an error is 'This value should not be blank' - I can't work out where I'm going wrong? It seems as if the data isn't binding to the form if it isn't valid, but instead of giving me the expected error, it just sees it as blank.

i.e. for the start field, I submit a string "this should be a date" - the error I get is for NotBlank, where as it should be for the not a date.

When stepping through the form bind process I noticed the following:

When the `Form/Form.php` hits the following line, the submittedData for date (which is a string - "2013-01-01") is set as an empty array - as soon as the loop is hit the array key is obviously not set, which is where the problem seems to stem from.

If I set a field to be an int, then submit a string, the `viewToNorm` method throws an error which when caught sets `synchronized = false` and the modelData and normData aren't bound.

**Entity:**

```
namespace HvH\DealsBundle\Entity;

class Deal
{
    private $name;
    private $start;

    // getters and setters here...
}
```

**Validation:**

```
# src/HvH/DealsBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
HvH\DealsBundle\Entity\Deal:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Type:
                type: string
        start:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Date: ~
```

**FormType:**

```
<?php

namespace HvH\DealsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class DealType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', null, array('description' => 'name'))
            ->add('start', null, array('description' => 'start'))
        ;
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'HvH\DealsBundle\Entity\Deal',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => false // have also tried this with true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'deal';
    }


}
```

Comment: put a custom message such as:  - NotBlank: { message: "Blank Name" } so you can know which field is failing you.

Comment: all fields respond correctly to -NotBlank, but if I submit any data and try to validate by NotBlank AND a Type, all I get is the NotBlank error, which isn't very helpful when the field is actually set. It's as if it is trying to bind first, failing, then trying to validate on the bound fields?

Comment: Which field is failing validation, name or start?

Comment: `name` will PASS if I submit an int, whereas `start` will fail if I submit an int but the error message will be for NotBlank rather than Date. I've tried stepping through the form bind process but can't work out where it validates

Comment: Did you try setting the option `required` to `false` on each field?

Comment: Yes - then the data passes even if it is submitted as an int

Comment: I just updated the question with debug info - the child elements (year, month, day) for the start field are not being populate on the form bind but they are initialized.